# When is Facebook FQL group table - version field > 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am using Facebook's FQL to retreive a list of groups that a user is in. Could some please give me some detail on what the "version" field is for.

The official docs say

> "> The group version. New groups are versioned > 0."

What is the definition of an "new group". Is it the new style groups that FB introduced a year or so ago? Are groups with a version < 1 considered obsolete?

Thanks

Pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Graph API documentation they do offer more information as to what new/old means.

> A flag which indicates if the group was created prior to launch of the
>   current groups product in October 2010
>
> int where 0 = Old type Group, 1 = Current Group

Comment: DMCS its been a while since i've been on stackoverflow. Answer not confirmed